# Google Schema Tag for site ratings/reviews not working

Tags: schema.org, google-schemas

I've added Schema Tags in order to show star ratings in google search like in the screenshot 
[image]

I've added the below code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://mysiteexample.com",
    "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://mysiteexample.com/search/?keyword={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string" },
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.8",
        "bestRating": "5.0",
        "ratingCount": "45"
    }
}
</script>
```

But it not being shown by google. I don't know what the problem is. I've also verified the schema tag from schema analyzer and its alright. Please help me understand what i'm I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This post on Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/119116/17633)

Answer (score 0):

Google does not always show review stars, even if the markup is syntactically correct. Check the Google structured data guidelines.

Some possible reasons:

- WebSite is not a specified type that can get review stars
- The page with the markup should clearly relate to what is being
  reviewed
- The reviews should be very visible on the page
- The reviews should be directly acquired by the page (submit review
  option?)
- Home pages do not get review stars